# How to get cluster IDs/Numbers (not just cluster centers) from Bisecting K-Means in Spark 2.0.2 (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am looking into the Bisecting K-Means algorithm of Spark MLlib (Scala). The Spark version I am using is 2.0.2.

Looking into the Spark example code (examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/ml/BisectingKMeansExample.scala) and methods of Bisecting K-Means, I am having a hard time understanding how should one retrieve the assigned cluster ID/numbers (not the cluster centers) from the class `BisectingKMeansModel`.

In the K-Means implementation of Spark/Scala, one can retrieve the clusters using `KMeansModel.summary.predictions`.

I was wondering if there is an efficient approach for retrieving the clusters (not the cluster center as the example depicts) from Bisecting K-Means model

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer for this question. It should be `KMeansModel.transform(dataset)`. This will add the cluster index as part in the dataset

Answer (score 0):

```
model.predict(vectordata)
```

This worked for me. If you do not want to lose you keys or other data you can call it likes this.

```
val NewData = data.map(t =>
(t._1,
model.predict(t._2)
)
```